# Linq-to-Xml, get element with a specific attribute

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have this XML,

```
<MM>
    <Bank>
        <Result>
            <url>http://192.168.1.12/pay/api/abc</url>
            <param name="type">FUND</param>
            <param name="tid">175219</param>
            <param name="ticket">DiZfWMQxL5Qfasfsdfsdfsqweqwe</param>
            <param name="stage">1</param>
        <Result>
    <Bank>
</MM>
```

I know how to get the value for the `url` element.

```
Dim qryurl = From c In doc.Descendants("Result") _
             Select c.Element("url").Value
```

How do I specific `param` tag values from the XML?

Comment: I've edited your question, I hope I haven't changed its meaning. Please use this as a guide for improving future questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
from x in c.Elements("param")
select new {
               type = x.Select(y => y.Attribute("name").Value == "type").Value,
               tid = x.Select(y => y.Attribute("name").Value == "tid").Value,
               ticket = x.Select(y => y.Attribute("name").Value == "ticket").Value,
               stage = x.Select(y => y.Attribute("name").Value == "stage").Value,

           }
```

There may be some syntax errors. But it is the logic to get values. You can check [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38534/LinQ-To-Xml-retrieve-element-value-by-its-attribut) for example about this topic.

Comment: I just tried your answer against the supplied XML and it didn't work. You may want to check it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look at doing it this way:

```
Dim getParam As Func(Of XElement, String, String) =
    Function (e, t)
        Return e _
            .Elements("param") _
            .Where(Function (x) x.Attribute("name") = t) _
            .Select(Function (x) x.Value) _
            .FirstOrDefault()
    End Function

Dim Query = _
    From c In doc.Descendants("Result") _
    Select New With 
    { 
        .URL = c.Element("url").Value,
        .type = getParam(c, "type"),
        .tid = getParam(c, "tid"),
        .ticket = getParam(c, "ticket"),
        .stage = getParam(c, "stage")
    }
```

You certainly could expand the `getParam` function directly into the query, but that would make it quite lengthy. Using the `Func` certainly shortens it down.

My result given the above code and your sample XML is:

[image: Query Result]